# FIGCAPTION ComObject with empty innerHTML and outerHTML when parsed with PowerShell 5?

Tags: html, powershell, comobject

I'm parsing this HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <figure>
        <img src="content/test.svg" alt="">
        <figcaption>Test caption.</figcaption>
    </figure>
</body>
</html>
```

with PowerShell 5. While the below approach works well for all relevant tags, including but not limited to div, p, table, td, tr, ... I seem to not figure out where the "Test caption." text is located in the object.

```
$html = New-Object -Com "HTMLFile";
$html.IHTMLDocument2_write($htmlContent);
$allTags = $html.all;
$allTags[8].tagName # is FIGURE
$allTags[9].tagName # is /FIGURE
```

But `$allTags[8].outerHTML` contains only `<FIGCAPTION>`. `$allTags[9].outerHTML` contains only `</FIGCAPTION>`. innerHTML is empty.

How can `$html.documentElement.outerHTML` still contain that figcaption text?

Also [this w3schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_figcaption_get) indicates that it should work like that. What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a compatibility issue. `<figcaption>` [requires IE9+](https://caniuse.com/?search=figcaption). Even if you have the latest IE version installed, the IE COM object might still choose to parse the HTML in compatiblity mode, which happens here.

Insert the [`X-UA-Compatible`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/ie_standards/ms-iedoco/380e2488-f5eb-4457-a07a-0cb1b6e4b4b5) meta tag to force the IE COM object to use the latest IE version:

```bash
$htmlContent = @'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
</head>
<body>
    <figure>
        <img src="content/test.svg" alt="">
        <figcaption>Test caption.</figcaption>
    </figure>
</body>
</html>
'@

$html = New-Object -Com HTMLFile
$html.IHTMLDocument2_write($htmlContent)

$allTags = $html.all
$allTags[8].OuterHtml   # <figcaption>Test caption.</figcaption>
$allTags[8].InnerHtml   # Test caption.
```

More info: [Towards Internet Explorer 11 Compatibility](https://geelaw.blog/entries/towards-ie11-compatibility/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast, precise and resolving answer. While I understand compatibility mode affects the parsing, I still don't understand where the output gets the figcaption text from. Anyways, kind regards from Austria!